# What sport is being referenced in the phrase "take one for the team"?

Tags: etymology, history

"Take one for the team" is a ubiquitous expression that can quickly be understood as putting yourself in an unfavorable position for the benefit of the larger group. But the expression itself references a team rather than "take one for us" or "take one for the group".

Is there a specific sport this phrase originally referred to before the general public started using it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Is there a specific sport this phrase originally referred to before the general public started using it?

Yes. Baseball.

From [idiomorigins.org](https://idiomorigins.org/origin/take-one-for-the-team):

> **Take one for the team**
>
> This expression derives from baseball and dates from the latter half of the 20th century c. 1970, and means that a player takes a pitch on the body in order to move to first base i.e. the player is making a sacrifice on behalf of the team. The player has to be careful because the umpire can penalise the player if the umpire believes it is deliberate. The expression has moved on to other sports, like (association) football, for example, where it means to commit a cynical foul and risk a yellow card in order to stop an opposing player from moving into a potential goal-scoring position. It is now frequently used outside of sporting contexts where it means to accept some chore or hardship for the sake of one's colleagues or friends.

Comment: Just as an aside, in 1990 the laws of football were changed to make the so-called "professional foul" a red card offence.

Comment: @richardb Of course that's football as we know it Richard. Our transatlantic friends would prefer "soccer".

Comment: @richardb It is, however, seldom given a red card  - unless "it is done to prevent a clear goal-scoring opportunity". Every week players commit yellow-card offences, where the commentators adjudge that "he took one for the team".

Comment: @BoldBen Well they'll have to get used to us calling it football. It is by a thousand miles the world's most important spectator sport, played in every country on the planet, and called something that roughly translates as "football" virtually everywhere - except the USA!

Comment: "The player has to be careful because the umpire can penalise the player if the umpire believes it is deliberate." Well, if it's inside the strike zone. If the pitcher is throwing the ball outside the strike zone to intimidate batters, it shouldn't be a penalty to stand your ground.

Comment: @WS2 It's called "soccer" in Canada, Australia, Ireland, Japan, Lesotho, South Africa, Liberia, New Zealand, Nigeria, Papua New Guinea, Philippines, and Singapore, and the word "soccer" comes from England.

Comment: @Acccumulation The only reason it got called that daft name in Britain was by the people who played Rugby, a vastly inferior game, as is evidenced by its much lower popularity internationally. They claimed the word "football". That is why Australia, New Zealand, and South Africa call proper football by a different name.  Rugby employs use of the hands as well as feet. Football is the only game that involves almost entirely the use of the feet - hence "foot-ball".  The Japanese are clearly misled by the Americans, though when I lived there I heard a lot about "football".

Comment: @Acccumulation The expectation in baseball is that players and coaches will conduct themselves in a sportsmanlike manner at all times. Moving so as to get hit is extremely unsportsmanlike conduct. Even standing ones ground is not sportsmanlike conduct. The sportsmanlike thing to do regarding a pitch that would otherwise hit the batter is for the batter to try move so as to avoid being hit by the pitch. That doesn't always work; batters are hit by pitches with regularity. Sometimes it's because the batter couldn't avoid being hit. But sometimes it's because the batter took one for the team.

Comment: 30 years on, @richardb, and the "professional foul" is still barely yellow-carded. If only they'd start throwing cards for taking a dive...

Comment: @DavidHammen "The sportsmanlike thing to do regarding a pitch that would otherwise hit the batter is for the batter to try move so as to avoid being hit by the pitch." So the batter should reward the pitcher for *their* unsportsmanlike behavior?

Comment: @Acccumulation The umpire can eject the pitcher if the umpire thinks the pitcher intentionally threw a pitch that would have hit the batter. It is not unsportsmanlike conduct on the part of the pitcher if it's just an unintentionally badly thrown pitch, and that does happen. Sometimes those bad pitches are in the dirt, sometimes far outside, and sometimes a bit too inside. Pitchers do squeeze the inside of the plate because that's where the batter is likely to get a lousy hit or broken bat. And sometimes those inside pitches go astray.